# Set different order email for each store view Mangento

Tags: configuration, magento-1.9, email-templates

I have two store views of my magento store. I want to set different email template with different logo for each store view. How can i do that? I searched for this but i found solution that work for only default store.

Any one can help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change logo and header and footer templates here.
**_admin->system->configuration->Design->Transactional Emails**

We can add more than one footers and header  for that, go to

**System > Transactional Emails->Add new template
[select templates as Email-footer or Email-header]**

And add the contents which you want and save the template
then you can see your new footer and  header which all you created here on

**_admin->system->configuration->Design->Transactional Emails->  Email Header Template/Email Footer Template [drop down]**

make the necessary changes against the store view and check

Change things for store views clear cache and check